# Sending multiple mails with Java in Unix

Tags: java, unix, runtime, mailx

how do I run Unix programs with Runtime in Java?
So far this is all I have. My plans are for the reciever mail to be varied so that I can run this in a loop with different recievers.

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process mailx = run.exec("cat Docs/Mailmsgtmp.txt | mailx -s 'Subject' -r 'sender@mail.com' " + "reciever@mail.com");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Runtime.exec()`, use a `ProcessBuilder`. Oh, and Java also has libraries for sending mails, so you needn't use an external command...

Anyway, with a `ProcessBuilder` you can redirect the standard input easily, which means in your case you can do this:

```
// recipient is the email address of the... recipient
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mailx", "-r", 
    "sender@foo.com", recipient);

final Path textToSend = Paths.get("Docs/mailtext.txt").toRealPath();
pb.redirectInput(textToSend.toFile());

// Also redirect stdout and stderr somewhere

final Process p = pb.start();

return p.waitFor();
```

Put this code into a method which can be, why not, a `Callable` and check for the return code. Use an `ExecutorService` if you want to send several mails at once.

See [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+sending+email&ia=qa) for many, many links on how to use pure Java to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Java's build-in mail package JavaMail.

Simple example from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm:

```
  // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
  String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

  // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
  String from = "web@gmail.com";

  // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
  String host = "localhost";

  // Get system properties
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();

  // Setup mail server
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

  // Get the default Session object.
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

  try{
     // Create a default MimeMessage object.
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

     // Set From: header field of the header.
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     // Set To: header field of the header.
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              new InternetAddress(to));

     // Set Subject: header field
     message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

     // Now set the actual message
     message.setText("This is actual message");

     // Send message
     Transport.send(message);
     System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
  }catch (MessagingException mex) {
     mex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

See https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home for extensive documentation.

Comment: Well, javamail is not really built in, but yeah, that's still better than using an external command. Just `.printStackTrace()` is not really the way I'd handle the error though :p